# Chat feature implementation in iOS

Tags: ios, windows, livechat

I would like to implement chat functionality in my app. I found XMPPframework which looks like what I am searching for. Since this uses xmpp protocol to run the chat, will this be installed on windows server?

Also the server guys in our team approached me for using of signalr objective c framework which uses websockets. Since server is windows, does I need to go with sigalr objective c framework? Signalr can be [found in github](https://github.com/DyKnow/SignalR-ObjC).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The client and server are independent. Don't worry if your client runs on iOS. The server can be implemented in any language, as long as it provides the services defined in the XMPP protocol.

Actually, you don't have to implement the server side yourself. There's already a bunch of server implementations that communicate with the clients through XMPP. The most commonly used one is [***Openfire***](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/).

On the client side, all you need to do is to send XML messages to the server and receive XML messages from the server. And obviously, someone already took care of that. There are XMPP client implementations too. Since I am a Windows Phone developer, I prefer [Matrix](http://www.ag-software.de/matrix-xmpp-sdk/). It provides simple client classes that communicate with Openfire servers. I'm sure you'll find the iOS equivalence to Matrix.

Good luck on your projects!